# Title page and abstract are numbered with the same roman numeral

Tags: titles, page-numbering, abstract

I am using the official LaTeX template of my university to write my thesis and I noticed that, when the .pdf file is compiled, the title page and the abstract page (both in different pages) are numebered by the same roman numeral i.

The fact that the abstract is numbered with the numeral i is correct. How can I change the title page numbering to another thing (for example, an A)?

I provide a MWE and some screenshots below. Thank you very much in advance.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myabstract}{\cleardoublepage}{\vfill\null}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
        UNIVERSITY\\
        FACULTY\\
        DEPARTMENT
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{3cm}
    \centering
    WORK TITLE

    \vspace{2cm}
    DEGREE

    \vspace{2cm}
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME

    \vspace{1cm}
    ADVISOR:\\
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME

    \vspace{1cm}
    COMMITTE MEMBERS:\\
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME\\
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME\\

    \vfill
    \normalfont
    Work funded by ORGANIZATION

    \vfill
    CITY\\
    YEAR
\end{titlepage}

\begin{myabstract}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{WORK TITLE}
    \end{center}
    \hfill
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{myabstract}

\end{document}
```

[image: numbering of title page]
[image: numbering of abstract (1-2)]
[image: numbering of abstract (2-2)]

Comment: The titlepage has no page number... The PDF viewer reports this, however, differently. Use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` etc.

Comment: You can change the pagenumbering using `\pagenumbering{...}` with possible values like `Roman` or `Alph`, etc. But the titlepage shouldn't be numbered at all.

Comment: `\frontmatter` switches to `roman` page numbering and the titlepage environment resets the page number at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\frontmatter` macro uses `\pagenumbering{roman}` at the end, so this switches to small roman figures and resets the page counter as well.

The `titlepage` environment does only reset the page counter at its end.

With two small adjustments the pagenumbering can be 'cured'. `\g@addto@macro\titlepage{\pagenumbering{Alph}}` will switch to 'Alpha' - counting of the page.

However, `titlepage` uses `empty` pagestyle, so `A` etc. is only visible in the PDF viewer or in the ToC, if this should be added to the ToC (which is rather unlikely). In this sense, the title page isn't numbered at all.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\titlepage{\pagenumbering{Alph}}
\g@addto@macro\endtitlepage{\pagenumbering{roman}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{myabstract}{\cleardoublepage}{\vfill\null}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
      UNIVERSITY\\
      FACULTY\\
      DEPARTMENT
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{3cm}
    \centering
    WORK TITLE

    \vspace{2cm}
    DEGREE

    \vspace{2cm}
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME

    \vspace{1cm}
    ADVISOR:\\
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME

    \vspace{1cm}
    COMMITTE MEMBERS:\\
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME\\
    NAME1 NAME2 SURNAME\\

    \vfill
    \normalfont
    Work funded by ORGANIZATION

    \vfill
    CITY\\
    YEAR
\end{titlepage}

\begin{myabstract}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{WORK TITLE}
    \end{center}
    \hfill
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{myabstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and solution! This is exactly what I wanted: to be able to "see" this differentiated numbering in the PDF Viewer. I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @IgnacioCorrea: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!